# How do I track down where event listener is getting added?

Tags: javascript

I have a fairly good sized javascript (with react/redux but no jquery) codebase for a webapp I'm building, and I've noticed that when I repeatedly open and close a certain panel within the UI, the number of listeners according to Chrome's performance timeline keeps increasing.

The graph looks like this:
[image: Graph of timeline]

I have allowed the chrome's performance monitor run for a good minute or two with the page sitting idle (just after opening/closing the panel a bunch), hoping that perhaps the listeners will get garbage collected, but they are not. I've switched to other tabs during this process, also hoping that the listeners will get garbage collected when the tab is backgrounded, but they unfortunately are not.

I therefore suspect that some listeners are getting registered that are never unregistered.

This leads me to two main questions:

1. Does my hypothesis that listeners are getting added and never
   unbound seems sensible, or is there more I could be doing to confirm
   this suspicion?
2. Assuming my suspicion is correct, how can I best go
   about tracking down the code where the event listener(s) is/are
   being added? I have already tried the following:

   - Looked at the code that is responsible for opening the panel in question,  seeing where it adds any listeners, and commenting out those portions to see if there's any change in the performance graph. There is not a change.
   - Overridden the addEventListener prototype like so:

```
var f = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, fn, capture) {
    this.f = f;
    this.f(type, fn, capture);
    console.trace("Added event listener on" + type);
}
```

Even after doing this, then commenting out all code portions that cause this console.trace to be executed (see #1) such that the console.trace is no longer printed upon open/close of the panel, I notice the same increase in listeners in the performance graph. Something else is causing the listeners to increase. I understand that there are other ways that listeners can be added, but it's not clear to me how to intercept all of those possibilities or cause them to be logged in Chrome's debugger in such a way that I can tell which code is responsible for adding them.

**Edit**:
 - At the suggestion of cowbert in the comments, I took a look at this page:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events

I then made the following function:

```
function printListenerCount() {
    var eles = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var numListeners = 0;
    for (idx in eles) { let listeners = getEventListeners(eles[idx]);
        for(eIdx in listeners)
        {
            numListeners += listeners[eIdx].length;
        }
        console.log("ele", eles[idx], "listeners", getEventListeners(eles[idx]));
    }
    console.log("numListeners", numListeners)
}
```

I execute this function after having opened/closed the panel a bunch of times, but unfortunately the "numListeners" figure doesn't change.
If the numListeners figure changed, I would be able to diff the results before/after having open/closed the panel to discover which element
has the extra event listener registered to it, but unfortunately numListeners does not change.

There is also a monitorEvents() API described on https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events, but the function
call requires that you specify a DOM element that you wish to monitor. In this situation, I'm not sure which DOM element has the extra
listeners, so I'm not sure how the monitorEvents() call will really help me. I could attach it to all DOM elements, similar to how I've
written the printListenerCount function above, but I presume I'd run into a similar problem that I ran into with printListenerCount() --
for whatever reason, it's not accounting for the listener(s) in question.

Other notes:
This is a somewhat complicated reactjs (preact, technically) based application. Like most reactjs based apps, components get mounted/unmounted (inserted into and removed from the DOM) on the fly. I'm finding that this makes tracking down "stray event handler registrations" like this a bit tricky. So what I'm really hoping for is some general debugging advice about how to track down "Stray event handlers" in large/complex projects such as this. As a C programmer, I would open `gdb` and set a breakpoint on everything that can possibly cause the "listeners" number in the performance graph to increase. I'm not sure if there's an analog of that in the javascript world, and even if it there, I'm just not sure how to do it. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the monitorEvents() API in chrome? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at that and added notes to my OP.

Comment: You may try searching for all instances of addEventListener in the code and place a breakpoint on them. Shouldn’t be very different from what you got with your prototype replacement, unless someone does the same thing before you do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, everyone. I ended up figuring this out.

From my OP:

> 1. Does my hypothesis that listeners are getting added and never unbound seems sensible, or is there more I could be doing to confirm this suspicion?

It turns out that the answer to this question is: The hypothesis is not sensible. The listeners simply haven't had a chance to get garbage collected yet. It can take some more time than you might think.

Here's how I figured it out:
I failed to realize that while recording a performance timeline, it's possible to force a garbage collection by clicking on the trash can icon in the Performance tab (same tab used to start the timeline recording). By clicking this icon after repeated closings/openings of the UI panel, the extra listeners completely went away. The graph now looks like this, with the dips being moments where I clicked the trash icon:
[image: Performance timeline with manual GC]

Apparently, backgrounding the tab and waiting a couple of minutes like I mentioned in the OP is simply not enough time for garbage collection to occur on its own; It takes some more time than that.

I wasn't aware of the ability to manually collect garbage with the trash can icon when I wrote the OP... I strongly recommend using it before going on any wild goose chases hunting down what might at first look like a performance problem.

Comment: Isn't the 'performance problem' here that you misunderstood/misinterpreted a graph? That is, there wasn't any actual measured performance problem, you thought there was one and ended up chasing your tail for a while. This can happen to anyone, of course but the solution to that is not 'find buttons in your tools UI that will make an imaginary problems go away' but 'try to get a better understanding of your runtime environment and what your tools are telling you'. I'm not sure the conclusion you've presented as an answer here is a good one.

Comment: I wonder if it is because when you "remove" an object, preact by default/still caches it in case you want to redraw it again, and it is cached with its handler still bound.

Comment: Right, in my OP I posted the following question "Does my hypothesis that listeners are getting added and never unbound seems sensible, or is there more I could be doing to confirm this suspicion?". It turns out the answer to that question was "Your suspicion that there was a real performance issue was incorrect, here's how you could have better made that determination...". I thought I made that pretty clear in my answer when I said "The hypothesis is not sensible.". If you find it unclear, can you point out why? Thanks.

Comment: I think I see where it may have been confusing, which was in the last sentence.

I changed the last sentence in my answer from:
"I strongly recommend using it when trying to narrow down any potential performance problems like this one."
To:
"I strongly recommend using it before going on any wild goose chases hunting down what might at first look like a performance problem."

Let me know if you still find it unclear.

Comment: My point being, yes I misinterpreted a graph. But part of my OP was essentially "Is there a possibility that I'm misinterpreting this graph? And if so, how can I be sure?". Because that was actually part of my original question, I think it's a perfectly acceptable answer to explain specifically how the graph was being misinterpreted and a method for how to prevent that particular misinterpretation in the future.

Comment: If the problem turned out to be a real problem, sure, it would make sense to insist on an answer to that real problem. Because the problem was an imaginary one, in my view the answer can only be "Here's why this problem was imaginary, and here's how to better detect this kind of imaginary problem in the future so you don't waste time on it."